# ASP.Net Core Identity Duplicate Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I've implemented [ASP.Net Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) in my Blazor Server Side project and all is working swimmingly with the exception of one issue which is that from time to time I find records within the table AspNetUsers with the same email address even though I have the below in my Startup class.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;                
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
})
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I extended the ApplicationUser to include DateRegistered and I note that in the duplicate rows the difference in DateRegistered is minuscule, for example

2021-03-17 09:58:11.2442397

2021-03-17 09:58:11.2442398

When implementing Identity I scaffolded the registration page and made one modification

Register.cshtml.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //check that the email address belongs to either a member, administrator or client
        var isValidRegistrationEmail = await _applicationUserDataService.IsEmailAddressValidForRegistration(Input.Email);

        if(isValidRegistrationEmail == false)
        {
            //we don't want to advise that the email address has not been found as this can be used by would be hackers
            return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, DateRegistered = DateTime.Now };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

            if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            else
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

The modification I made was the insertion of the below code as in this application only selected email addresses should be able to register.

```
//check that the email address belongs to either a member, administrator or client
var isValidRegistrationEmail = await _applicationUserDataService.IsEmailAddressValidForRegistration(Input.Email);

if(isValidRegistrationEmail == false)
{
    //we don't want to advise that the email address has not been found as this can be used by would be hackers
    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
}
```

When investigating the issue I did note that the database on the production server was missing the index UserNameIndex which I've now added.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex] ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
(
    [NormalizedUserName] ASC
)
WHERE ([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The addition of the missing index would seem to me to prevent duplicate entries now being added to the table AspNetUsers however I'm wondering whether this will completely resolve the issue or whether users will now receive an error due to the application attempting to add a second record with the same email address.

It's difficult to test as it doesn't happen every time.

Comment: surely an error will be reported to the user (if your server handles all errors to return a message to clients). So you need to solve the problem of why the record being duplicated when adding a new user.

Comment: I'm considering whether the addition of the missing index will resolve the issue or whether that was only part of the problem and I introduced an issue when I modified the registration page

Comment: that's part of the issue, you still need that missing index. It's kind of a guard (validator) on the database layer. The remaining issue is wrong behavior done by the app layer which will cause unnecessary non-sense error reported to the client. Your system will be good because no data will be duplicated but the UX is still not good because of users seeing weird errors reported sometimes, although the data is still submitted/saved OK.

Comment: Yes. That's my fear as I'm not sure what is causing the problem at the application layer as I'm just using the boiler plate registration code with the exception of the one addition I outlined and I can't see how that could cause the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't have a definitive answer, or I don't know what the underlying issue is. But I think the index does not prevent duplicates from registering as per [this line](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs#L415) in the ASP.NET Identity repo. So, my best answer is that creating the index won't resolve whatever the underlying issue is. Also remember that the duplicate protection is on the `UserName` column, not `Email` specifically. This is a little confusing because they can be effectively the same in a typical registration scenario. I don't think your scaffolding and custom page is an issue, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

delete entities from database and rerun sql service in your system then retry